Usign too many form element in component/page
Is it okay to have many  on the page without any visible input? I'm reading about useActionState in react doc and in their example they are using  for adding a product to card
https://react.dev/reference/react/useActionState
I want to know about this pattern
So if we have three button on each product card, Is it okay to have three forms in that component? And we can have several instance of that component in a page  

As long as forms are not nested, it's fine.
